# Loop corrections to propagator (QFT of Srednicki)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, propagator

Perhaps this is a very basic question.

In chapter 14 of Srednicki's QFT textbook (2007), $O(g^2)$ loop corrections to the propagator of $\phi^3$ theory is discussed. However, I don't know how to derive the Eq. 14.34 on page 103 (I can't present the full context as it would be too long).
From 
\begin{equation}
\Pi(k^2)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha\Gamma(-1+\epsilon/2)\int_0^1\,dxD(4\pi\mu^2/D)^{\epsilon/2}-Ak^2-Bm^2+O(\alpha^2),   (14.32)
\end{equation}
and take the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit using
\begin{equation}
A^{\epsilon/2}=1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}ln(A)+O(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}
and the following property of Gamma functions
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(-n+x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{x}-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-1}+O(x)\right],
\end{equation}
he got
\begin{equation}
\Pi(k^2)=-\frac{1}{2}\alpha\left[\left(\frac{2}{\epsilon}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}k^2+m^2\right)+\int_0^1\,dxDln\left(\frac{4\pi\mu^2}{e^\gamma D}\right)\right]-Ak^2-Bm^2+O(\alpha^2), \qquad (14.34)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha\equiv\frac{g^2}{(4\pi)^3}$.

I don't know how to do the integral correctly (although it seems elementary). Can anyone familiar with this part help me out?

Comment: What is $D$ ? Does it depends on $k$ and $x$ ? If it is only the integral over $x$ that you don't know how to do, it might be easier just to give it directly (or ask Mathematica)...

Comment: @Adam : $D= x(1-x)k^2 +m^2$, see [link](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5OepxIG42B4C&pg=PA100&dq=Srednicki+14.14&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=GMfBUsKZN4qw0QWM-oDADQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Srednicki%2014.14&f=false) (14.14)

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to give D. Trimok is correct. The author also used
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\,dxD=\frac{1}{6}k^2+m^2,
\end{equation}
which is easy knowing $D=x(1-x)k^2+m^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's not a problem if one simply omits the $O(\epsilon)$ terms since we are taking the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit. The author just didn't state it clearly.

Comment: The term with the integral is $O(1)$, not $O(\epsilon)$ and it can not be omitted (without changing regularisation scheme).